# HashTable .Net exception of null instance

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I'm using .Net 2.0, and I've run into a strange error:

I have a hashtable using string as keys and a class (named Market) as the value.  The class contains 4 integers and 1 byte. One of the integers represents a counter which I need to increment.

I have only one element in the hashtable.  It's key is `"Tomo"`.

I do this:

```
string strM = "Tomo"
MarketPlace mkt = (MarketPlace)mHash[strM];
mkt.nCter++;
```

In the last line I get an null reference exception, even though using the debugger I can see that the hashtable contains that instance.   This code was working fine a week ago.

Comment: You are using .NET 2.0. Why are using Hashtable? Use `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`

Comment: Why ? HashTable is not allowed on .NET 2.0 ?

Comment: It's there for backwards compatibility to .Net 1.1/1.0.  You really shouldn't use it otherwise.

Comment: Is using enumorator is safety on .NET 2.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

Locate the place where you do *one* of the following:

```
mHash[strM] = mkt;
mHash.Add(strM, mkt);
```

At that location, `mkt` is `null`.

Edit: This is based on the fact that you stated that you verified the `Hashtable` contains the key. If in fact the `Hashtable` did *not* contain the key, the following applies:

> If the specified key is not found, attempting to get it returns `null`.

Comment: It contains the key which is not null, even a function before uses that instance of the class.

Comment: Check again - it's not the key that's null, it's the value `mkt` that's null. Also, is the `NullReferenceException` thrown even when you have a breakpoint set on the line `Market mkt = (Market)mHash[strM];`? This is a key piece of information in the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using .NET 2.0, I recommend using a `Dictionary<string, Market>` instead of a HashTable.  It will provide type safety, and probably help you realize why you are having the issue in this case.

Comment: The casting to type will be done anyhow, so what is the benfit from this solution ? can u explain more ?

Comment: You avoid boxing, which can cause (potentially) some issues like you're seeing.  You also get type safety - so you make sure that both the code that's adding to the collection, as well as the receiving side, are doing things the same way.  In your case, you're probably either adding in a null reference, adding in with the wrong key, or retrieving with the wrong key.  Having type safety helps the compiler check the most common mistakes in this process.  As a side benefit,  you'll get better performance with generics, since you avoid boxing.

Comment: It makes for more readable, easier to debug code. (Also, the runtime will already know beforehand that the object can be cast to the needed type, which saves it from checking)

Comment: In this case, there is no boxing going on though. Market class for values (ref type) and strings for keys (ref type).

Comment: @Thorarin: That's true - no boxing with strings or "Market", unless "market" is a struct instead of a class.

Comment: Is using enumorator is safety on .NET 2.0 ?

Comment: You can enumerate the dictionary in .NET 2.0 with full type safety.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not just looking at the key in the Hashtable, where the value is null?

For example, this works:

```
mHash["Tomo"] = null;
Market value = (Market)mHash["Tomo"];
value.nCounter++; // NullReferenceException
```

Comment: I'm sure it contains an instance of a class.

Comment: One of your assumptions must be wrong, or you wouldn't be getting this error :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you added your instance backward.

```
mHash.Add(instance, "Tomo")
```

instead of

```
mHash.Add("Tomo", instance)
```

So when you are in debugger, it may appear as if it's listed, but the key is actually the instance and "Tomo" is the object value.